# Output from clasp list contains strange characters

Tags: bash, shell, clasp

I am building a script that gets the project name from the clasp and creates a directory. Everything is going fine but the directory is named weirdly.

This is what I am doing

Get the information regarding the project

```sh
info=$(clasp list)
declare -p info
```

output is `\E[2K\E[1Gnotify-slack-from… – https://script.google.com/d/18S6ot_3uvqGNujti3XPqOTTQwxYUEnr_j0y2GMQcFvWStg5ZIyCPURiN/edit`

Here is the output of `clasp list | hexdump -C`

```
00000000  1b 5b 32 4b 1b 5b 31 47  6e 6f 74 69 66 79 2d 73  |.[2K.[1Gnotify-s|
00000010  6c 61 63 6b 2d 66 72 6f  6d e2 80 a6 20 20 20 e2  |lack-from...   .|
00000020  80 93 20 68 74 74 70 73  3a 2f 2f 73 63 72 69 70  |.. https://scrip|
00000030  74 2e 67 6f 6f 67 6c 65  2e 63 6f 6d 2f 64 2f 31  |t.google.com/d/1|
00000040  38 53 36 6f 74 5f 33 75  76 71 47 4e 75 6a 74 69  |8S6ot_3uvqGNujti|
00000050  33 58 50 71 4f 54 54 51  77 78 59 55 45 6e 72 5f  |3XPqOTTQwxYUEnr_|
00000060  6a 30 79 32 47 4d 51 63  46 76 57 53 74 67 35 5a  |j0y2GMQcFvWStg5Z|
00000070  49 79 43 50 55 52 69 4e  2f 65 64 69 74 0a        |IyCPURiN/edit.|
0000007e
```

I dont want the strange characters at the start of the string.

After doing the above, I split the string into two at ' - ' using

```sh
projectname=(${info// - / })
```

After this, I create a directory using

```sh
mkdir $projectname
```

This creates a directory with name `\033[2K\033[1Gnotify-slack-from…`
What I want is a directory with the name `notify-slack-from…`

Any idea what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: use `declare -p info` to see all characters, including potentially nonprinting characters, on the `info` variable. Edit your question to include that, and you'll probably want to change your question title. `mkdir` is not adding characters to your dirname, your variable contains strange characters.

Comment: @jeremysprofile Thanks for the reply. I have updated my question. Can you please help me out here.

Comment: Add output of `clasp list | hexdump -C` to your question.

Comment: @Cyrus, what are you looking for that `declare -p info` does not provide? Asking for my ability to help on future questions.

Comment: It looks like `clasp` is unconditionally outputting ANSI escape sequences for formatting, assuming that it is writing to a terminal. The odd thing is what that formatting is: `\e2K` clears the current line, then it writes the byte `\x4b`, moves the cursor *back* to the first column with `\e[1G` (presumably to overwrite the `\x4b`, the outputs the rest of the data. There might be an option to `clasp` to prevent that from being output in the first place.

Comment: Hello @chepner. Thanks for your time. So how can I get `notify-slack-from…` from the output?

Comment: @jeremysprofile: The output of `hexdump -C` is the quickest way to solve the problem as each byte is precisely broken down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that it appears to be a prefix of fixed size you want to remove, you can use

```
projectname=${projectname:8}
```

to trim the leading 8 bytes from the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
pn=$(echo "${projectname}" | cut -d'G' -f2)
```

The above works, too.